# Wrong behavior when I try to apply the UV grid texture to my object

Tags: texturing, materials, uv

I'm trying to apply the UV grid textures to my character,but for an unknown reason,it did not work as expected. When I go in **Object mode** and then I change the **texture viewport shading** to **Textures**,the look of the skin don't change. It should look like a grid chess,but,instead are the eyes to change look,infact they seem to be darker. Where is the error ? thanks.

[image: 1]
[image: 2]
[image: 3]

While,it worked in a earlier version (the white,blue,black are the colors of the eyes) :

[image]

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the first screenshot, it seems that the penguin has no material, unlike in the last screenshot where the penguin has 3 materials assigned (and there it shows the texture)..?

[image]

Could it be just this?

**Edit:**
Following you request in comments/chat, I did a test:

1.I  downloaded your file, saved on my desktop

2. I created a new default file in blender
3. I appended just the penguin **mesh** from your file (I found it's named "untitled" in your file, under "mesh" folder.
4. Then I selected my default cube object, and switched to the "object data" in its properties panel
5. From the "browse mesh data to be linked" selection tool, I selected the previously imported penguin mesh, named "untitled".
6. Now my "cube" object has a penguin shape. Your UV grid also gets imported.
7. Setting viewport shading to "textured" shows the textured penguin!

[image]

So, I think the object in your file was corrupted, but the mesh is fine.

You can correct your file in this way, I think.

Btw, your mesh has arms normals inverted, select all mesh vertices, and fix them (<kbd>CTRL</kbd><kbd>N</kbd>).

This is my file:
[image]

Hth.

Comment: Is this a question or an answer?

Comment: I attached the blender file. Check it out. And check the last picture : you will see the colors of the eyes,but not the color of the skin....

Comment: @cegaton could it be a questionable answer?,In my native language, this is a way of answering... it's a way to express my feeling that the error could be a really basic one... iif it's not not acceptable, I could edit and transform the "question"  into an affirmative phrase...

Comment: also check the latest attached picture...I added a material,but it does not work anyway...

Comment: yes it is weird. I added a texture (missing) to the material, I added a cube and the grid texture shows just fine. tried to recalc normals (on arms are inverted). Did you import this model?

Comment: no. I created it by myself.

Comment: Appended the "untitled" mesh (not the "bird" object) in a new file, and I can UV texture it with the grid, and it shows...  something happened with that object, maybe. Which blender version did you use?

Comment: 2.76 on the beginning,and at some point,2.77

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/39563/discussion-between-m-ardito-and-marietto).

Comment: m. ardito,are you still there ?

Comment: yes, use the above link to get into the chat...